# Data encryption

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, encryption

Since all data on the Blockchain is public. Presume I have multiple users submitting data which I want to hide, is there a way I can encrypt that data on the Blockchain ?

Or do I have to encrypt off-chain then pass them over on-chain?
If so any recommendations of data encryption algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

No, Ethereum does not support any data encryption schemes directly.

You have encrypt data off-chain and then send it to the blockchain in encrypted format. You can't have any encryption keys or similar in the blockchain as everything is public.

You can use whatever encryption you want as it's not related to Ethereum/blockchain at all.